# What is the différence between Instances and Individuals views in Protégé OWL

Tags: owl, protege

In Protégé OWL Editor (Desktop version 5.0.17) there are various views for Individuals. See picture below.
[Protégé different views for indiviudals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlhwA.png)

Among them there are Individuals and Instances Views. What are the differences between instances and individuals ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between an individual and an instance in OWL. All individuals are instances of one or more classes. Looks like a case of ambiguous names.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that in Protege, 'instance's are only 'individual's DIRECTLY ATTACHED to the selected 'class', whereas 'individual's refer to both 'instance's attached to the selected 'class' AND ALSO all its child 'class'es recursively.

Comment: yes but it looks like individual's DIRECTLY ATTACHED to  owl:NamedIndividual